# change font-awesome icon when toggled

Tags: jquery, css, html, font-awesome

I've been trying to find a way to change this icon  to fa-times when my menu is toggled then change back to fa-bars when the menu is toggled back/close.

I've tried some codes already they're in this jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/3RBQ4/39/

```
<nav class="primary_nav">
    <label for="show-menu" class="label-show-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="services">Services</a>
            <!-- <ul>
                <li><a href="">Building</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Plumbing</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Electrician</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Roofing</a></li>
                </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="quote"><span class="get-quote">Get a Quote!</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none;
}
.label-show-menu {
    display: none;
}
#menu {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#menu.expanded {
    background: red;
    max-height: 500px;
}

@media  (max-width:632px){
    .label-show-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

JS

```
$('#show-menu').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('.label-show-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars').addClass('fa fa-times')
    $('#menu').toggleClass('expanded');
 });
```

Comment: You need to target your `i` element

Comment: You don't even need JavaScript for this

Comment: @royhowie please show your way of doing this?

Comment: @nCore I just got home. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @nCore I posted the CSS-only solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to use a hidden checkbox. A label is then used to target the checkbox. Since checkboxes receive the `:checked` pseudo class, when toggled, you can use this to style sibling elements. Let's walk through it.

Here's the HTML, for reference:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <label for="toggle">
        <i id="bars" class="fa fa-bars fa-fw"></i>
        <i id="cross" class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
    </label>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
            <li>item one</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first thing we want to do is hide that ugly checkbox! No one wants to see it.

```
#toggle {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But how can we toggle the checkbox, if it's hidden? Easy. Use a label:

```
#toggle + label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Now it's just a matter of using the `:checked` pseudo class properly.

```
/* by default, the menu should be hidden */
#menu {
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    /* removed other styling */
}
/* when the checkbox is checked, hide the bars icon */
#toggle:checked + label i#bars{
    display: none;
}
/* and show the cross icon */
#toggle:checked + label i#cross{
    display: block;
}
/* and, of course, give the menu a height */
#toggle:checked ~ #menu {
    height: 85px;
}
```

And voila! You have a menu that doesn't use any JavaScript. Here's a

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/r8p0hs3b/2/)

Answer (score 2):

For one, you should be targeting the child, `i`, element. In addition, you should change the class(es) based on whether or not the menu element has the class `expanded`.

(i.e., `$('#menu.expanded').length`).

```
$('#show-menu').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#menu').toggleClass('expanded');
    $('.label-show-menu i').removeClass().addClass(
        $('#menu.expanded').length ? 'fa fa-times fa-2x' : 'fa fa-bars fa-2x'
    );
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xpu1zbp/)

Also, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate(). http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

I use double toggleClass for `<i>` element

```
$('#show-menu').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('#menu').toggleClass('expanded');
    $('.label-show-menu i').toggleClass( 'fa-times');
    $('.label-show-menu i').toggleClass( 'fa-bars');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/230d7stx/